# express Failed to load resource CSS/JS

Tags: node.js, express

I building socket.io app using express, originally had all CSS/JS in index.html and used

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

but now I split CSS/JS to seperate files `app.css` and `app.js` but when I start the app and visit page in Console Log in browser I get

Failed to load resource errors for the CSS/JS, what should I do so it also allows seperate CSS/JS?

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express'),
     app = express(),
     http = require('http').Server(app),
     io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
http.listen(port);
```

index.html will be displayed at http://localhost:[port].